# Bluetooth does not detect devices on lenovo with 12.04

Tags: 12.04, bluetooth, lenovo, realtek, realtek-wireless

I am new to Ubuntu and I am not good at this, but I did a clean install on my **Lenovo Z5070** with **Ubuntu 12.04** and **3.13 kernel** all by myself.

My **bluetooth** can not detect devices, I have tried `blueman` as well but it didn't work.

So my results from `lsusb` etc. are:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.     
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver   
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 045e:0039 Microsoft Corp. IntelliMouse Optical   
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.    
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174f:14b2 Syntek   
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:b728 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.   
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  

[    0.174128] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored  
[    4.554899] rtl8723be: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723befw.bin  
[    4.978542] psmouse serio1: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x594f03)   
[    6.117875] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PEGP) defines _DOD but not _DOS   
[    6.608236] r8169 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2   
[    6.610477] r8169 0000:01:00.0 eth0: unable to load firmware patch rtl_nic/rtl8168g-3.fw (-2)    

0: hci0: Bluetooth    
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
2: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
3: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  

[    2.250559] usb 2-7: Product: Bluetooth Radio   
[    4.109311] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17  
[    4.109334] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized  
[    4.109340] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized  
[    4.109341] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized  
[    4.109353] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized  
[    6.178347] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3  
[    6.178349] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast  
[    6.178356] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized  
[    6.184069] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized  
[    6.184079] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized  
[    6.184084] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11  

Linux maria-Lenovo-Z50-70 3.13.0-51-generic #84~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed   Apr 15 21:45:46 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux  

bluetooth             411194  14 rfcomm,bnep,btusb
```

I can not understand what I'm reading in these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers generic
wget https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au_bt/archive/troy.zip
unzip troy.zip
cd rtl8723au_bt-troy
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and see if it works as there might still be a second part to get it working.

I thought the lwfinger wifi drivers needed to be used so

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
cd rtlwifi_new
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and see if it is fixed

If you get a new kernel through updates, bluetooth will fail until a kernel is made with support for the realtek bluetooth, until then you will need to

```
cd rtl8723au_bt-troy
make clean
make
sudo make install
cd ~/rtlwifi_new
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Then you should be able to reboot and have bluetooth functional again

Comment: Oh! It took a second boot and for the first time it detects the device. The problem now is that it fails to connect on both normal setup and blueman.

Comment: I added info on installing the wifi drivers that are needed

Comment: It is now pairing and connecting so your work here is done!
I still can't see the connected device  in sound settings thus I can not choose to listen from it. I guess this is a totally different issue.
Thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: If you have blueman as a bluetooth manager you will need to `sudo pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover` after every boot as a bug in blueman will unload module bluetooth discover.  I will also add instructions for what to do after a kernel update

Comment: What about upstream integration ? I am tracking this at http://rzr.online.fr/q/ideapad

Comment: It is being worked on rzr, see [here](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth-next.git/commit/drivers/bluetooth/btusb.c?id=a2698a9bf9b0cfcf7e556946e04c4456a13a6f5a)

Comment: @Jeremy31 I made a ppa for the bt driver.

Answer (score 0):

I added this driver to a ppa. "kernel" branch should be used for newer kernels.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8723au-bt-dkms
```

The advantage of installing this way is that the driver will stay after kernel updates.